# Returning a random new initialized object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class called Item and a bunch of items that extend Item.
Is it possible to hold these classes an in an array and return a newly initialized object of any of these classes?
My goal is a random item drop.
I'm using typescript, but an example in javascript should work too.

So for some reason this works:

```
 var items: any[] = [];
        items.push(Coffee);
        items.push(Kamikaze);
        return new items[0](game, x, y);
```

it will return a new Coffee object
but this won't:

```
 static allItems: any[] = [Coffee,Kamikaze];
```

globally and then this in the function:

```
return new this.allItems[0](game, x, y);
```

it will also work if i declare this globally:

```
    static allItems: any[] = [];
```

and then run this in the function:

```
   this.allItems.push(Coffee);
        return new this.allItems[0](game, x, y);
```

but i need these declared statically so i cant keep pushing them in

Comment: Please post your code in the question.

Comment: You want instances in the array, and the to return a clone of one of them at a random index?

Comment: exactly, only i want them in a static array

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array of constructors and randomly select a constructor from that array and then create a new object with it:

```
// existing constructor functions
function A() {
    this.type = "A";
}

function B() {
    this.type = "B";
}

function C() {
    this.type = "C";
}

// array of constructor functions of the various types of objects
// you want to select from
var items = [A, B, C];

// function to randomly select constructor function and create an object with it
function getRandomItem() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    return new items[rand]();
}

var newItem = getRandomItem();
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/BsLaX/

Comment: this could work, but would add a lot of code (i would have to add a new function for each item) and it would be a lot better if i could initialize the object directly out of the array.
It works when i don't initialize the array with the elements, but i want to know how to get it to work when the elements are intialized with the array

Comment: @user3293629 - If you have a custom object defined, then it's constructor is already defined.  In this example, `A`, `B` and `C` are constructor functions defined for particular types of objects.  I thought you said you already had multiple custom object types defined, so you just use the constructors, not make new functions.  In the code you've now added to your question, these constructors would be `Coffee` and `Kamikaze`.  They already exist.

Comment: i dont fully understand

Comment: @user3293629 - instead of my `A`, `B` and `C` constructor functions, put the names of your object's constructors like `Coffee` and `Kamikaze` into the items array.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding an init() method

```
      static init() {
        this.allItems.push(Coffee);
        this.allItems.push(Kamikaze);
        this.allItems.push(LazerGun);
        this.allItems.push(Shield);
        this.allItems.push(SniperGun);
    }
```

now it works

Comment: Why not just: `this.allItems = [Coffee, Kamikaze, LazerGun, Shield, SniperGun];` like I did in my answer?